# MySQL How to combine two tables (different fields) with two statements

Tags: mysql

I want to combine two tables that have different columns.  The reason is that I'm using Report Builder (http://wpreportbuilder.com/) that support only one database source and one .docx template.

First table:

```
CLIENT    DATE             TITLE      NAME      SOLUTION
 ABC      2019-03-01     title123   compA       fix1234
 ABC2     2019-03-01     title124   compB       fix12345
```

Second table (could have more columns):

```
CLIENT      DATE          CUSTOMER    REPORT       PHONE
 ABC3     2019-03-01         abc       PDF         1234
```

Desired output

```
CLIENT        DATE      TITLE     NAME    SOLUTION   CUSTOMER   REPORT    PHONE
 ABC      2019-03-01  title123   compA   fix1234      
 ABC2     2019-03-01  title123   compB   fix12345
 ABC3     2019-03-01                                  abc        PDF     1234
```

That way I can easily use my .docx template with {title.all} , {name.all}, {report.all} and import values from the database automatically and insert them back in the word doc.

I can easily do it if the number of columns is matching but if # of columns doesn't match (like my code below), it's returning an "not matching error".

My code:

```
SELECT 

 client AS Client,
 date as "Date Scanned",
 scanner AS Scanner,
 risk AS Risk, 
 host AS Host, 
 name AS Title, 
 solution AS Solution

FROM sss1_latest
WHERE risk regexp "High" 


UNION

SELECT 

client AS Client,
date as "Date Scanned",
Recommendation AS Solution
FROM sss2_latest
WHERE Recommendation regexp "fix1"
```

The above code doesn't reflect my first/second table above.  It was just for explanation purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the queries in a `UNION` have to select the same number of columns. You can select `NULL` or `''` as placeholders for the columns that only exist in the other table.

```
SELECT 

 client AS Client,
 date as "Date Scanned",
 scanner AS Scanner,
 risk AS Risk, 
 host AS Host, 
 name AS Title, 
 solution AS Solution,
 '' AS Customer,
 '' AS Report,
 '' AS Phone

FROM sss1_latest
WHERE risk regexp "High" 


UNION

SELECT 

 client AS Client,
 date as "Date Scanned",
 '' AS Scanner,
 '' AS Risk, 
 '' AS Host, 
 '' AS Title, 
 '' AS Solution,
 Customer,
 Report,
 Phone

FROM sss2_latest
WHERE Recommendation regexp "fix1"
```